# Extract values from column based on other column in excel

Tags: excel

I am new to excel. I have an excel sheet similar to the following table(Date,Id)

```
Date        Id
02.06.2014  314
            315
            316
            317
            318
03.06.2014  326
            327
            328
            329
04.06.2014  347
            348
05.06.2014  356
            357
            358
            359
```

I need to extract start id and end id for each day and my resultant should be like the following table(Date,Start id,End id)

```
Date        Start id  End id
02.06.2014  314       318
03.06.2014  326       329
04.06.2014  347       348
05.06.2014  356       359
```

The sheet is too big to do it manually. Is there any way to automate the process in excel . If so Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is pragmatic, trying to keep it fairly simple but allowing you to automate the process as you asked. It requires a little bit of manual action and only works if the values in the column `id` are unique.

[image: Screenshot to guide the answer]

The first step is to condense column `A` to remove the empty cells. This can be done with a so-called array-formula as explained on several places on the web, for example [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2007/09/16/excel-remove-blank-cells/). In the example sheet, I used

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$16, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($A$2:$A$16), "", ROW($A$2:$A$16)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$16))+1), ROW(A1)))
```

for cell `D2` and then confirmed this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it an array formula. The formula will be surrounded by curly brackets. Cell `D2` should now contain the first date value. Now grab the lower right corner of `D2` and pull it down to populate the other values. If you pull down far enough, you will have all values. After that, you will get `#NUM!`. If that is a problem, check out the earlier link on how to avoid that by using the `IFERROR()` function.

Next is the formula for `E2`:

```
=LOOKUP($D2,$A$2:$A$16,$B$2:$B$16)
```

Again, pull down the lower right corner to fill the other fields in `E`. Note that this formula only works if the values in column `B` are unique. If that is not the case, a more complex formula is needed.

Finally, to populate column `F`, use

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$16,MATCH($E3,$B$2:$B$16)-1)
```

in cell `F2` and pull down. Note that this formula does not work for the last value in column `F`. The easiest is to manually fill out that value or, if you do not like that, search the web for a formula to find the last value in column `B`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution without any formulas will be something like this... but you need to set up the oroginal data like below...**that is repeat Date labels**.. (which is easier to do as a clean up exercise)... e.g. Type "=A2" in Cell A3.. then select the range A3 to A16 or END for example.. Press Ctrl+G.. Click Special... Choose Blanks... which will select all the blank cells... and do a Ctrl + V to Paste the formula... which will automatically fill in the dates for each row based on previous row...

[image]

```
Date    ID
02/06/2014  314
02/06/2014  315
02/06/2014  316
02/06/2014  317
02/06/2014  318
03/06/2014  326
03/06/2014  327
03/06/2014  328
03/06/2014  329
04/06/2014  347
04/06/2014  348
05/06/2014  356
05/06/2014  357
05/06/2014  358
05/06/2014  359
```

Then do a pivot table.. with Date in Rows.. and Min of ID and Max of ID in Values.. Example as below..

[image]

Please let me know if this helped you.. in the comments.

Comment: This one is cleaner for my requirement. Thank you.